# Error in SharePoint Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, sharepoint-hosted-app, sharepoint-rest-api, app

I am creating a SharePoint hosted app in which i am fetching a SharePoint list data and showing it on html page . Whenever i am making the rest API call , i am getting " Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource error".

[image]

I have full access on the list and SharePoint site as well . Can anybody please tell me why i am getting this error ?

Comment: Are you fetching list data from the **AppWeb** or **HostWeb** ?

Comment: Using HostWeb .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If so, you need to use **Cross Domain** to overcome this issue apply this code below in your **app.js**

**JSOM Method**

```
'use strict';
var hostweburl, appweburl;
var myList;

$(document).ready(function () {
    appweburl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
    hostweburl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;

    var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";

    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
        function () {
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", retrieveListItems);
        }
    );
});

function retrieveListItems() {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
    var appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostweburl);
    myList = appContextSite.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("yourListTitle");
    context.load(myList);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onGetWebSuccess, onGetWebFail);

    //the remaining code is omitted for clarity  
}

function onGetWebSuccess() {
    alert("calling" + myList.get_title());
}

function onGetWebFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Failed to get lists. Error:' + args.get_message());
}
```

**Rest API Call**

```
var executor; 
executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl); 
executor.executeAsync( { 
    url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/Folders@target='" + hostweburl + "'", 
    method: "GET", 
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }, 
    success: getSuccessHandler, 
    error: getErrorHandler 
}
```

For more details about **Cross Domain** follow this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2012/11/29/solving-cross-domain-problems-in-apps-for-sharepoint/)

Comment: Thanks for instant reply Youssef . I need to do the same using REST only .

Comment: You are welcome @RohitKharade you will find above updated answer with Rest API Call.